# Reading Avro table and schema stored in HDFS using Spark- Java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, avro

I am trying to read an Avro table stored in HDFS specifying also the schema
which is also stored in HDFS.
For the moment I have this solution that seems to work:

```
    RDD<String> stringRDD = sparkContext.textFile(schemaPath, 1);
    String [] collect = (String []) stringRDD.collect();
    String schema = collect[0];
    Dataset<Row> df  =sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.avro").option("avroSchema", schema)
            .load(tablePath);
```

Is this the best way to do that?
What if the schema is big enough to have 2 partitions for example? Should I merge all of them using reduce()?

Cheers

Comment: Why do you need to read the schema in the first place? It is possible to read an avro without a schema (as the schema is embedded in the avro). Have you tried to just skip the schema option?

Comment: Schema may also be described directly in a class (as a field, created by hand) without needing to get it from an external file, is it an option?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's been a year since this was asked, but I was recently looking to do the same thing and this question came up on top in google.

So, I was able to do this using Hadoop's FileSystem class:

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

String schemaPath = "/path/to/schema/in/hdfs.avsc";
FSDataInputStream schemaFile = FileSystem.get(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration).open(new Path(schemaPath));
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaFile);
String schemaString = schema.toString();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using Spark 2.1.1

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema
val avroSchema = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(source).take(1)(0)._2
val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(avroSchema)
```